# Using subqueries with multiple results which depend on the main query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a persons table called "tc_person" and a marriage table called "tc_marriage". I want to select a few columns from my persons table and one column which represents the id of the partner.

The marriage table includes the pid_1 and pid_2 of two people - but it is important that there is only one entry for a couple and the order of the couples ids may vary. Here's the tables:

tc_person:

```
|   id    |    name    |   lastname  |
--------------------------------------
|    4    |    peter   |    smith    |
|    5    |    sarah   |    smith    |
```

tc_marriage:

```
|   id    |    pid_1   |    pid_2    |
--------------------------------------
|    0    |      5     |      4      |
|    1    |      7     |      9      |
```

It seems that my subquery is interpreted as a whole before the original select statement. Now I get the error that my subquery returns more than one row.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.lastname,

(SELECT m.pid_1 FROM tc_marriage m WHERE m.pid_2 = p.id UNION
 SELECT m.pid_2 FROM tc_marriage m WHERE m.pid_1 = p.id) as partner_id

FROM tc_person p WHERE p.lastname LIKE 'smith';
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
|   id    |    name    |   lastname  |  partner_id  |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    4    |    peter   |    smith    |       5      |
|    5    |    sarah   |    smith    |       4      |
```

Is this even possible with only one single query? You can probably tell by now that I'm quite the SQL noob. Maybe you guys can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IN to avoid a UNION (which is typically slower), and a CASE statement to pick out the correct partner_id:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.name, 
       p.last_name, 
       CASE p.id WHEN m.pid_1 THEN m.pid_2 ELSE m.pid_1 END AS partner_id
FROM tc_person p
JOIN tc_marriage m ON p.id IN (m.pid_1, m.pid_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to join the person table to the marriage table.  However, the problem is that you have two keys.  One solution is to do two joins and then some logic to choose the right value.

I prefer to "double" the marriage table by swapping the partners.  The following query takes this approach in a subquery:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.lastname, partner_id
from tc_person p join
     (select pid_1 as firstid, pid_2 as partner_id
      from marriage
      union all
      select pid_2 as firstid, pid_1 as partner_id
      from marriage
     ) m
     on p.id = m.firstid
```